# Angular 4 execute function from another component without using Services

Tags: angular

i have a login component, In this component i'm using Dialog Box for login dynamically which is also accessible from other component. In this component we have logout function (to logout user). 
so how i can execute logout function form other component which is present in Login component.

export class loginComponent implements OnInit {

```
let postdata = {
     email:email,
     password:password
 }

  this.register.customerLogin(postdata).subscribe( (response) => { response; });
```

}

logout() {

```
 localStorage.removeItem('cemail');
 localStorage.removeItem('cname');
 localStorage.removeItem('cid');
 localStorage.removeItem('token');
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Drop the "without using Services" from your arbitrary requirements, since a service is precisely what you should use.

Comment: Exactly! Use the service

Comment: @DavidVotrubec Thanks for ans.

Is any other way to do this ?

Comment: Yes, you can use custom events which will bubble up the DOM and then react to those events, but it is more work and it depends on how your components are related to each other in the DOM. So the service is the easiest and recommended way

Comment: Thanks
@DavidVotrubec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are better but if you want execute child component methods you can use **@ViewChild()**

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

 @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.child.myMethod());
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Services are better option but you can use @Output and EventEmitter to create a event and emit from child to parent and pass data from parent to child using @Input.